# Brightcove SmartPlayer API Controlling Volume

Tags: javascript, volume, brightcove

I am using Brightcove custom player, it has only videoDisplay ( not video control ). In JavaScript i am creating all media control like ( play/ pause, Seek bar, volume , fullscreen).

I am able to play, pause, seek video via smartplayer API. But i didn't find a method to mute / unMute or adjusting volume.

From Brightcove support website i found a article to control volume via JS
http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/solutions/controlling-volume-player-api

setVolume method throws undefined error

But i don't find a method video.setVolume() in VideoPlayer API
http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/reference/symbols/brightcove.api.modules.VideoPlayerModule.html

Help me controlling volume via JavaScript

Thanks

Comment: setVolume method works only in Flash only video player.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure this out to - I need a video to auto-play (its going to be used in an ad unit) and have it be muted by default.

From the link you provided, see the following note:

> Note: Volume control has not been included in the Smart Player API.
>   iOS devices do not allow for control of the volume outside the
>   built-in system controls (i.e. cannot be done via Javascript).
>   Controlling the volume programmatically in any HTML player is
>   currently not possible.

I'm thinking the solution might be to use the Flash Player API where it is supported with auto play and mute, and then fall back to the Smart Player API without auto-play everywhere else.

I'm also looking into video.js as an alternative - but if the note from the BC knowledge base is correct, thats not going to work.